# How to get from Poitiers TGV station to Futuroscope-du-Poitou

Tags: public-transport, france, buses

I will be arriving at the TGV train station in Poitiers (from the direction of Paris if that matters) and from there I want to travel to the Futuroscope-du-Poitou site, where I'd prefer public transportation.

What are my best options?

Until now, I've found some information, but it doesn't provide me a useful itinerary yet:

- There are apparently [many buses](http://www.raileurope.co.uk/Default.aspx?tabid=716) leaving from the TGV station in Poitiers
- There is some [scheduler for Poitiers](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/), but it confuses me, as there are two TGV stations in the scheduler, which seem to be the same, and close to where I actually need to be. I was expecting the TGV station to be somewhere in the city of Poitiers, instead of the suburbs.

Any advice on a possible itinerary and correction of a mistake is more than welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two stations in Poitiers where TGV stop: [Poitiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Poitiers) (the downtown train station), and [Futuroscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_du_Futuroscope). Some trains from Paris only stop at downtown Poitiers, others stop at Futuroscope on the way.

Futuroscope is served by line 1 (Monday to Saturday), line 1E (1 express, Monday to Friday), and line E (Sundays and public holidays). From the Futuroscope TGV station, it's a short walk. From the city, take the bus. There are [11 stops around the site](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/content/download/1963/10971/version/1/file/plan+du+site+du+futuroscope.pdf), select the one that's closest to where you're going. On the way to the Futuroscope, all three lines have “Futuroscope” in their destination. The website seems to be currently broken, I can't access the schedules. You can get schedules for your day of travel from the [interactive trip planner](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/itineraires/recherche). For the train station in Poitiers, use *Gare SNCF (Poitiers)*.

You can buy a [bus ticket](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/Tarifs2/Voyageurs-occasionnels/Le-ticket-a-l-unite) from the driver, in cash (1.30€). Exact change is recommended but drivers will give back change if they can. The ticket is valid for 1 hour. You can also buy a ticket from the regional ticket machine in the station. If traveling with other people, you can buy [5 tickets](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/Tarifs2/Voyageurs-occasionnels/Le-carnet-de-tickets) for a slightly reduced price (5.20€) from the machine in the station. There's also a [day ticket](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/Tarifs2/Voyageurs-occasionnels/Le-ticket-jour-decouverte) valid for up to 4 people traveling together, which is cheaper for as few as 2 people making a return trip within the day (3.80€), but it isn't for sale at the station vending machine: you have to find a [ticket agent](http://www.vitalis-poitiers.fr/S-informer/Lieux-d-accueil-et-de-vente) (there is one outside the station: exit to the east (right side when coming from Paris) and cross Boulevard du Grand Cerf to bar-tabac Le Printania at number 139).

If you're standing at a bus stop and your bus is coming, signal the driver by waving your arm. Press the “stop requested” (“arrêt demandé”) a little before the bus reaches your destination stop.